# better format data pulled from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

asked a question a couple days ago about formatting data pulled from an api and i got some fantastic answers! though, im getting the following error on pages that the api doesnt have data for certain assets:

[image]

for example (with the code highlighted above removed):

[image]

```js
    const columns = [{
      title: 'Rank',
      ...
    }, {
      title: 'Symbol',
      ...
    }, {
      title: 'Name',
      ...
    }, {
      title: 'Price',
      dataIndex: 'Price',
      key: 'current_price',
      render: (value) => {
        return <span>$<b>{value.toFixed(2)}</b></span>;
      },
    }, {
      title: 'Market Cap',
      ...
      },
    }, {
      title: 'Change (24hr)',
      dataIndex: 'priceChange',
      key: 'price_change_percentage_24h',
      render: (value) => {
        return <span><b>{value.toFixed(2)}</b>%</span>;
      },
    },
    }];
```

TL;DR im having trouble trying to give me the results that i currently have and *not* give me an error when null. BIG BONUS POINTS for anyone who can help me also only show 2 numerals after the decimal point IF greater than 1.0 and 3 or 4 numerals after the decimal point if less than 1.0 for prices (as shown below)

[image]

i apologize for the noobish question but i can't seem to come up with a solution and figured id learn best if someone could kindly assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isNaN()` to check if it's not a number and show empty string
then check for greater than 1 and use 2 decimals
else use 3 (or 4 if you like)

```
return (
  <span>
    <b>
      {isNaN(parseFloat(value)) ? '' : value > 1 ? value.toFixed(2) : value.toFixed(3)}
    </b>
    %
  </span>
);
```

Comment: this is what im getting on those pages https://i.imgur.com/alSY8uK.png :/ 

certainly one step forward though!